React is not rendering .png photos on browser
I'm working on a small workshop app, but I have trouble displaying the photos of the cars in the browser.
I just get the placeholder on an image

import React from "react";

function Products() {
  const cars = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Toyota Camry",
      price: 25000,
      img: "../assets/images/toyota_camry2023.png",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Honda Civic",
      price: 27000,
      img: "../assets/images/honda_civic2023.png",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Ford Mustang",
      price: 35000,
      img: "../assets/images/ford_mustang2023.png",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Find The Best Deals</h2>
      <h2>Available Cars</h2>
      <ul>
        {cars.map((car) => (
          <li key={car.id}>
            <img src={car.img} alt={car.name} />
            <h3>{car.name}</h3>
            <p>Price: ${car.price}</p>
            <button>More details</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Products;

Tried all solutions previously provided in Stackoverflow about a similar issue but it did not work.

The path is correct, I double checked it, thanks

Use import toyota from '../assets/toyota.png'
const cars = [{ ...car, img: toyota }]
or add files in public folder and use absolute path from public folder.

it worked with this method, thank you. But in case I have too many cars, am  going to import each individually >

when I tired adding them in public previously, it did not work, but now all good, thank you.

The correct way, this files should be in server and return url to front to use in array.

Thank you, it is a small project, I do not actually have an API for it.

import React from 'react';

function Products() {
  const cars = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Toyota Camry', price: 25000, img: require('../assets/images/toyota_camry2023.png').default },
    { id: 2, name: 'Honda Civic', price: 27000, img: require('../assets/images/honda_civic2023.png').default },
    { id: 3, name: 'Ford Mustang', price: 35000, img: require('../assets/images/ford_mustang2023.png').default },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Find The Best Deals</h2>
      <h2>Available Cars</h2>
      <ul>
        {cars.map(car => (
          <li key={car.id}>
            <img src={car.img} alt={car.name} />
            <h3>{car.name}</h3>
            <p>Price: ${car.price}</p>
            <button>More details</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Products;

